# Using syms command with for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, symbolic-math

I need to solve some equations using syms. On solving it, it is showing error as given below

```
 Error in syms (line 201)
toDefine = sym(zeros(1, 0));

Error in Speciation(line 1)
syms a b c d
```

Another doubt I am having is, I need to run this code with more than one values of x1, x2, x3, and T (vectors), for which I was trying to apply for loop but I am not getting how to generate vectors of symbols using syms accurately and how will statements(such as S.a(S.a<0)=[])in code will change in code. If I could please get some help

```
 syms a b c d
    x1= 0.5096;
    x2=  0.0963;  
    x3 = 0.3941;
    T= 394.15;
    K1=exp((-228.838)+((12587.48)/T)+(40.68593*(log(T)))+(-0.09838*(T)))
    K2=exp((-2.326+(-1233.57/T)))
    K4=exp((-936.28)+((40216.27)/T)+(151.983*(log(T)))+(-0.1675*(T)))
    K5=exp((1044.78)+(-45171.42/T)+(-165.20*log(T)+(0.1511*(T))))
    S=solve(((b*3*b)/((a-b)*(x3)))==K5,(a*(a-b))/(((x1-d-a))*(x2-d-2*c))==K4,(d*d)/((x1-d-a)*(x2-d- 
 2*c))==K2,(c*c)/((x2-d-2*c))==K1)
    S.a=double(S.a);
    S.b=double(S.b);
    S.c=double(S.c);
    S.d=double(S.d);
    S.a(S.a<0)=[];         
    S.b(S.b<0)=[];
    S.c(S.c<0)=[];
    S.d(S.d<0)=[];
    m = min(S.a)          
    n=min(S.b)
    o=min(S.c)
    p=min(S.d)
```

Comment: You can solve a system of equations by putting them in a vector; i.e. `solve([a*b == K1; 3*b == K2])` and so on. And you can make assumption on symbolic variables, so if all your symbolics are positive, you can define them with `syms a b c d positive`

Comment: It is still showing this error Error in syms (line 201)
toDefine = sym(zeros(1, 0));

Error in Speciation (line 1)
syms a b c d positive

Comment: Ah, maybe you have a custom function `zeros`, check [this](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/254878-errors-when-using-syms-function) link

Comment: built-in (C:\Users\Desktop\Matlab\R2018a\toolbox\matlab\elmat\zeros)
C:\Users\Desktop\Matlab\R2018a\toolbox\distcomp\parallel\@codistributed\zeros.m      
C:\Users\Desktop\Matlab\R2018a\toolbox\distcomp\parallel\@codistributor1d\zeros.m   
C:\User\Desktop\Matlab\R2018a\toolbox\distcomp\parallel\@codistributor2dbc\zeros.m  
C:\Users\Desktop\Matlab\R2018a\toolbox\distcomp\parallel\@distributed\zeros.m        C:\Users\Desktop\Matlab\R2018a\toolbox\distcomp\gpu\@gpuArray\zeros.m                
C:\Users\Desktop\Matlab\R2018a\toolbox\coder\float2fixed\@half\zeros.p

Comment: These are the files shown by MATLAB and I think these all are in built.